# Hosting Font-Awesome file on local server

Tags: html, css, datatables

I am using `DataTables` and in order to use the icons for the pagination buttons I am using font-awesome. I downloaded the file and there are two files

1- font-awesome
2- font-awesome.min

Which one do I need to add in my css to get the Forward, Next Previous icons and do I need to add any other files with it.

Currently I linking `font-awesome.min.css` but I don't see the button icons in my pagination

Thanks

Comment: Please show the files as referenced in your html file.

Comment: font-awesome.css and font-awesome.min.css are the same. One is the CSS minify (font-awesome.min.css) and one is not minify. Please provide your code in a Fiddle if you want us to help you.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that you have not pasted fonts folder in your project directory,

Comment: Girdhari, do I need to add the folder or just the files?

Comment: Copy the folder, it have few files, and source code of `font-awesome.min.css` also points to directory,

Comment: `- css
 -- font-awesome.min.css
- fonts
-- all files`
This should be the format (css files parent should be sibling of fonts folder)

Comment: Your problem resolved?

Comment: No. I have an integration folder under it i pasted fonts folder which has all the files. Is this what you are trying to say?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font Awesome not working on local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44977254/font-awesome-not-working-on-local)

Comment: Did you check to see if you are getting 404 errors on your servers?  In my IIS server, I had to make changes to the web config file before they worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local folder structure should be like this

```
|--- assets/
|    |--- font-awesome/
|         |--- fonts/
|              |--- FontAwesome.otf
|              |--- font-awesome-webfont.eot
|              |--- font-awesome-webfont.svg
|              |--- font-awesome-webfont.ttf
|              |--- font-awesome-webfont.woff
|         |--- css/
|              |--- font-awesome.css
```

And Link your project like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
```

Finally in your stylesheet (for eg: change sorting icon)

```
        table.dataTable thead th {
            position: relative;
            background-image: none !important;
        }

        table.dataTable thead th.sorting:after,
        table.dataTable thead th.sorting_asc:after,
        table.dataTable thead th.sorting_desc:after {
            position: absolute;
            top: 12px;
            right: 8px;
            display: block;
            font-family: FontAwesome;
        }
table.dataTable thead th.sorting:after {
    content: "\f0dc";
    color: #ddd;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    padding-top: 0.12em;
}
table.dataTable thead th.sorting_asc:after {
    content: "\f0de";
}
table.dataTable thead th.sorting_desc:after {
    content: "\f0dd";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use font awesome CDN Link

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

If is not working still please update your html code

Comment: I have to get it in my local. No CDN.

Comment: Ok update your code i will check. I can't  understand what the exact error

Comment: For my IIS server, I had to change the web .config before fontawesome loaded. Does that apply?